# Why does Helgrind show "lock order violated" error message?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, valgrind, deadlock

Please see the following code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    pthread_mutex_t g = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mutex_t m1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mutex_t m2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    void* worker(void* arg) 
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&g);

        if ((long long) arg == 0) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);
        } else {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&g);
        return NULL;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        pthread_t p1, p2;
        pthread_create(&p1, NULL, worker, (void *) (long long) 0);
        pthread_create(&p2, NULL, worker, (void *) (long long) 1);
        pthread_join(p1, NULL);
        pthread_join(p2, NULL);
        return 0;
    }
```

Helgrind throws the following error:

```
==10035== Helgrind, a thread error detector
==10035== Copyright (C) 2007-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP et al.
==10035== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10035== Command: ./Hw5
==10035== 
==10035== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==10035== 
==10035== Thread #3 was created
==10035==    at 0x538987E: clone (clone.S:71)
==10035==    by 0x5050EC4: create_thread (createthread.c:100)
==10035==    by 0x5050EC4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:797)
==10035==    by 0x4C36A27: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x1088BD: main (Hw5.c:28)
==10035== 
==10035== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==10035== 
==10035== Thread #3: lock order "0x309080 before 0x3090C0" violated
==10035== 
==10035== Observed (incorrect) order is: acquisition of lock at 0x3090C0
==10035==    at 0x4C3403C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x10882E: worker (Hw5.c:16)
==10035==    by 0x4C36C26: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x50506DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==10035==    by 0x538988E: clone (clone.S:95)
==10035== 
==10035==  followed by a later acquisition of lock at 0x309080
==10035==    at 0x4C3403C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x10883A: worker (Hw5.c:17)
==10035==    by 0x4C36C26: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x50506DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==10035==    by 0x538988E: clone (clone.S:95)
==10035== 
==10035== Required order was established by acquisition of lock at 0x309080
==10035==    at 0x4C3403C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x108814: worker (Hw5.c:13)
==10035==    by 0x4C36C26: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x50506DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==10035==    by 0x538988E: clone (clone.S:95)
==10035== 
==10035==  followed by a later acquisition of lock at 0x3090C0
==10035==    at 0x4C3403C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x108820: worker (Hw5.c:14)
==10035==    by 0x4C36C26: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x50506DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==10035==    by 0x538988E: clone (clone.S:95)
==10035== 
==10035==  Lock at 0x309080 was first observed
==10035==    at 0x4C3403C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x108814: worker (Hw5.c:13)
==10035==    by 0x4C36C26: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x50506DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==10035==    by 0x538988E: clone (clone.S:95)
==10035==  Address 0x309080 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "m1"
==10035== 
==10035==  Lock at 0x3090C0 was first observed
==10035==    at 0x4C3403C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x108820: worker (Hw5.c:14)
==10035==    by 0x4C36C26: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==10035==    by 0x50506DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==10035==    by 0x538988E: clone (clone.S:95)
==10035==  Address 0x3090c0 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "m2"
==10035== 
==10035== 
==10035== 
==10035== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10035== Use --history-level=approx or =none to gain increased speed, at
==10035== the cost of reduced accuracy of conflicting-access information
==10035== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 7 from 7)
```

I think the outer lock `g` will not allow two threads to enter the critical section at same time.
Only one thread can acquire the lock `g` at a given time. So I think there is no possibility for a deadlock. Am I worng? Why helgrind is throwing this error? Please explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Helgrind is complaining that your threads are observed to lock mutexes `m1` and `m2` in different relative orders, which is clear also from inspection of the code. Helgrind looks for and flags such differences in acquisition order because, generally speaking, they produce a risk of deadlock.

> I think the outer lock `g` will not allow two threads to enter the
>   critical section at same time. Only one thread can acquire the lock `g`
>   at a given time. So I think there is no possibility for a deadlock. Am
>   I worng?

You are not wrong.  The particular program presented will not deadlock because each thread has to acquire `g` before it can acquire either of the other mutexes.

> Why helgrind is throwing this error?

Because helgrind's is an *heuristic* analysis of the *runtime behavior* of your program during *one run*.  It does not assume that a single run of the program demonstrates all possible behaviors.  Your evaluation, on the other hand, is based on source code analysis.

The heuristic rule you're seeing in action here is that no pair of mutexes should be acquired in different relative orders by any thread.  For your particular program, this produces a false positive, but your program seems engineered specifically to produce such.  There is no need for mutexes `m1` and `m2` in the first place if mutex `g` will always be held when either of the others is acquired.  If it were possible for any other thread to acquire `m1` and `m2` without holding `g`, however, then the deadlock risk would be genuine, regardless of acquisition order in said other thread.

Any way around, then, the warning signals a genuine issue with your code: either you are performing unneeded mutex operations, or you have genuine present or future deadlock risk.